# Intermediate linux and mysql server connection in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I have 3 linux server. Last one is mysql server. Now in PHP we are connecting second linux server by using ssh_connect.

```
Second server config = {
   host: 192.168.32.10,
   username: 'root',
   privateKey: '/home/raj/prj/mykey',
   port: '22'
}

$conn = ssh2_connect('192.168.32.10', 22);
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn, 'root', '/home/raj/prj/mykey.pub', '/home/raj/prj/mykey');

third mysql server config {
  host: '192.168.32.11',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'secret',
  port: '3306'
}
```

From second server, how to connect third mysql server and get "MySQL Uptime"?

Comment: Why not just SSH tunnel through and connect over 3306 via a forwarded port?

Comment: How ? can you write the example.

Comment: You have some homework to do. I'm just providing advice here. SSH tunnelling is a very simple way to bridge connections, and it makes it possible to use regular PHP code to interface with remote servers.

Comment: $tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($conn, '192.168.32.11', 3306);  in this code, where i need to pass username /password and how to execute the uptime command

Comment: The SSH functions in core PHP are pretty weak. You might want to find [a library](https://packagist.org/search/?q=ssh) that can set up a port-forwarding tunnel.